# Multiple-enabled Select Causing Server-Side Error

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I have a form that I am passing to an apps script function. One of the form elements is a list box that allows the user to make multiple selections. Whenever one item is selected from the list box, the function (which uploads an image from another input element) runs fine, but whenever two or more items are selected, the function throws a failure. While the function never makes use of the list box, is there some reason why it being part of the form might cause issues with passing it into the function, and how can I fix it?

HTML snippets:

```
  <form id="classForm">
 <img id="previewImg" width=300px>
<input type="file" name="imageLoader" id="imageUpload" accept="image/*"      onchange="upload();">
<select multiple="true">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //This function stub passes in the form to a function that uploads a user-provided image for preview use
 function upload(){

    var form = document.getElementById("classForm");

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(uploadResult).uploadFile(form);
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(uploadResult).uploadFile(form);
 }

  //This function displays a preview of the user's ad image
 //Data in: id of image, to be used to generate url
function uploadResult(url){

   url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + url;

    $('#previewImg').attr('src', url);
 }

//clears input so that onchange will fire even if user selects same image
$(document).on("click", "#imageUpload", function() {

   this.value = null;

 });
</script>
```

The function (called from upload, which does some processing and then sends in the form):

```
function uploadFile(form) {
 // Name of folder where the files should be saved
var folderName = "AdImages";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);

//Find the folder, create if the folder does not exist
if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
}

// Get file from form as blob
var blob = form.imageLoader;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    

// Set the file description to something
file.setDescription("title"); 


//get picID

var picId = file.getId();

// Return the id of the picture, to be used to construct the previewable url
return picId;
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? A multi-select will give a comma-separated list of values, so you'd need to handle that - but what is the `upload()` function doing? Your snippets aren't enough to reproduce the problem, so it's hard to help you. [mcve]

Comment: Sorry about that -- I rebuilt a minimal version of the program to reproduce the problem and updated the details above. I went over the logs and no error message appears, but it still runs as though it's throwing the withFailureHandler.

Comment: I would recommend encasing your uploadFile() function in a try-catch statement and logging the message so that you can see exactly what is causing the error.

Comment: The exact error I receive is NetworkError: Form submission failed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by wrapping the file input element in its own form. It's admittedly a hacky solution, but since I only need access to that one particular element for the function in question, it gets the job done.